# Intermediate results in the forward method of my torch neural net have requires_grad=False

Tags: python, pytorch

I have defined a small neural net in PyTorch, and tried to train it. However, the loss did not have requires_grad set - that was curious. I set a breakpoint in the forward method of my neural net, and none of the intermediate variables created (embs, means, sim, out) had requires_grad set.

Here is my code:

```
class Cbow(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, hctx_len, emb_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Linear(in_features=vocab_size, out_features=emb_size, bias=False)
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(in_features=emb_size, out_features=vocab_size, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        # x: (num_batches, 2*hctx_len, vocab_size)

        embs = self.proj(x)               # (num_batches, 2*hctx_len, emb_size)
        means = embs.mean(dim=1)          # (num_batches, emb_size)

        sim = self.hidden(means)            # (num_batches, vocab_size)
        out = torch.softmax(sim, dim=1)     # (num_batches, vocab_size)
        # breakpoint()

        return out


def fit_model_layers(model, train_loader, epochs, lr=0.01):
    model.train()

    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    for e in range(epochs):
      running_loss, num_batches = 0, 0
      for x, y in train_loader:
          out = model(x)

          # calculate loss
          loss = loss_fn(out, y)                # loss.requires_grad = False !!!!!!
          running_loss += loss.item()
          num_batches += 1

          # backprop + optimization step
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()
          optimizer.zero_grad()

      print(f'Epoch {e+1} loss: {running_loss / num_batches}')
```

I don't quite understand what I do wrong. In the optimization example from PyTorch (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html) intermediate results in forward() all have requires_grad set.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unable to reproduce. I ran the code you provided and the loss term has `requires_grad=True`.

```py
class Cbow(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, hctx_len, emb_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.proj = nn.Linear(in_features=vocab_size, out_features=emb_size, bias=False)
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(in_features=emb_size, out_features=vocab_size, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        # x: (num_batches, 2*hctx_len, vocab_size)

        embs = self.proj(x)               # (num_batches, 2*hctx_len, emb_size)
        means = embs.mean(dim=1)          # (num_batches, emb_size)

        sim = self.hidden(means)            # (num_batches, vocab_size)
        out = torch.softmax(sim, dim=1)     # (num_batches, vocab_size)
        # breakpoint()

        return out
    
vocab_size = 64
hctx_len = 128
emb_size = 128
bs = 12

model = Cbow(vocab_size, hctx_len, emb_size)

x = torch.randn(bs, 2*hctx_len, vocab_size)
y = torch.randint(0, vocab_size, (bs,))

out = model(x)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = loss_fn(out, y)
print(loss.requires_grad)
> True
```

Additionally, `CrossEntropyLoss` includes the softmax operation - applying a softmax in the model before the loss is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I was able to run the code in another environment and it produced no issues.

Regarding softmax, is its use utterly incorrect or just superflous/wasteful?

Comment: Check the CrossEntropyLoss [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html). The loss module computes both the softmax and the log likelihood loss. You don't want to softmax before the loss module because then you're softmaxing twice. You will have to softmax the model outputs when using the model for inference.